# Rename yup error key based on other value

Tags: javascript, validation, yup

I have an array of objects which contain the same values including locale.

Locale is a language: en, de

I have this schema:

```
descriptions: yup.object().shape({
      data: yup.array().of(
        yup.object().shape({
          name: yup.string().required('required'),
          locale: yup.string().oneOf(['de', 'en']),
        })
      ),
    })
```

I want to get errors returned like this:

```
{ descriptions: { data: [{ name_en:"required"}, ...] } }
```

I tried to do it with `.label()` but, it returns the same key or I'm doing it wrong.

Also I tried with `transformKeys` like this:

```
  .transformKeys(key => `${key}_something`)
```

Even if this works, I still need access to the locale value

Comment: Label() should work. You must have added after the wrong function. add it after `.string().label()`